# Удаление отдельных переменных в ключе реестра с помощью cmd/bat

Tags: cmd

Здравствуйте.Есть путь реестра **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Mytest**,в нем есть параметр **LIST**, в который забито построчно 3 переменные.

Задача: Проверить данный параметр на наличие посторонних переменных и удалить их, не затронув те 3, которые были занесены изначально.

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную задачу исключительно с помощью cmd/bat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пока нет дополнительной информации, могу лишь посоветовать команду reg.exe, которая появилась начиная с windows xp. Читайте помощь к утилите, может сами справитесь, или уточняйте сам вопрос.

Ps может есть смысл заглянуть в сторону powershell?

Comment: к сожалению доступны лишь функции cmd/bat. решение уже найдено как раз при помощи reg.exe. подсказал пользователь evlanoff с Биткода. Но тем не менее - спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то никто не мешает использовать для сохранения/восстановления ветки реестра вызова в командной строке собственно `regedit /e имя_файла.reg ИМЯ_ВЕТКИ` для экспорта в файл и `regedit /s имя_файла.reg` для импорта из файла! Таким образом можно сохранять только нужные параметры ветки реестра, вместо чтоб искать лишние.

Comment: это не совсем то. дело в том что батник который необходимо создать должен запускаться на разных машинах(**только** батник, без резервных ключей реестра), на одних системах параметр LIST будет чист, на других нет. необходимо что бы батник в *полуавтоматическом* режиме выполнял очистку, без помощи пользователя. на данный момент реализовано примерно как вы посоветовали - выполняется проверка на содержимое, инфо выводится на экран, если есть лишние строки - пользователь нажимает кнопку - удаляется данный ключ и создается новый, но для этого необходим юзер, это не приемлемо.

Comment: А откуда можно знать, какие ключи лишние? Есть на самом деле способ ещё проще первого: запретить юзерам изменять определённые ветки реестра! Но я не уверен, что это работает на всех версиях Виндов. Кроме того, это требует некоторого умения настройки юзерских политик.

Comment: "правильные" данные заложены в условия исполняемого кода, все лишние данные удаляются если будут найдены. то что вы советуете не подходит, по скольку для этого необходим предварительный доступ к системе, для заперта доступа к реестру. это невозможно. доступа нет, есть лишь готовая машина на которой необходимо выполнять код для очистки ключа реестра. такие условия задания, другого не дано.

Comment: Хотя - для чего тогда ловить лишние строки? Ну, пока известна тактика, но непонятна стратегия! Может, откроете, наконец, для чего это всё нужно?

Comment: Уважаемый, если вы не в состоянии понять суть вопроса то не пытайтесь ответить и уж тем более не стоит хамить! флаг вам в руки и советую идти лесом.

Comment: Прошу прощения за то, что не сумел прочитать Ваши мысли!